# Kivymd APK crashes after building with google colab, any clue in the logs?

Tags: android, kivy, kivymd, buildozer

I build the apk file successfully with google colab following this recipe: https://dev.to/ngonidzashe/how-to-use-google-colab-to-package-kivymd-applications-with-buildozer-46bl

Using the debugging tool ant filtering on "kivy" I get the following:

````
2022-08-15 13:07:26.632 1477-3299/? I/ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=org.mm.myajpp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity bnds=[38,1414][291,1709] mCallingUid=10313} from uid 10313
2022-08-15 13:07:26.645 1477-3299/? D/CompactWindowManagerService: onOriginListAdded child: ActivityRecord{2620236 u0 org.mm.myajpp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity t2478}; parent: Task{23017d1 #2478 type=standard A=10422:org.mm.myajpp U=0 visible=true mode=fullscreen translucent=true sz=1}
2022-08-15 13:07:26.646 1477-3299/? D/TaskExtImpl: add ActivityRecord{2620236 u0 org.mm.myajpp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity t2478} to mActivityRecordSum = Counter{ org.mm.myajpp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity(1) }
2022-08-15 13:07:26.647 1477-3299/? D/ActivityTaskManager: getStartingWindowType: newTask=true, taskSwitch=true, processRunning=false, allowTaskSnapshot=true, activityCreated=false, snapshot=null, record:ActivityRecord{2620236 u0 org.mm.myajpp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity t2478}
2022-08-15 13:07:26.703 1477-2038/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 12493:org.mm.myajpp/u0a422 for pre-top-activity {org.mm.myajpp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity}
2022-08-15 13:07:26.750 1477-1914/? D/CompactWindowManagerService: updateBackgroundSurface openingApp: ActivityRecord{2620236 u0 org.mm.myajpp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity t2478}
2022-08-15 13:07:26.797 1477-6058/? I/OplusAppSwitchManagerService: appswitch hasProcess ActivityRecord{2620236 u0 org.mm.myajpp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity t2478}
2022-08-15 13:07:26.798 1477-6058/? I/OplusAppSwitchManagerService: appswitch hasProcess ActivityRecord{2620236 u0 org.mm.myajpp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity t2478}
2022-08-15 13:07:26.798 1477-6058/? I/InputDispatcher: setFocusedApplication displayId=0 ActivityRecord{2620236 u0 org.mm.myajpp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity t2478}
2022-08-15 13:07:27.140 1283-1283/? D/OplusLayer: setBuffer sequence=62511, name=org.mm.myajpp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity#0
2022-08-15 13:07:27.151 1477-1914/? I/Quality: LaunchTime2.0: org.mm.myajpp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity 1 499
2022-08-15 13:07:27.155 1477-1889/? I/ActivityTaskManager: Displayed org.mm.myajpp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity: +521ms
2022-08-15 13:07:27.161 1477-6054/? I/FocusResolver: updateFocusedWindow, 5cf6bc4 org.mm.myajpp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity on display 0, reason: Window became focusable. Previous reason: NOT_VISIBLE, result:   FocusedWindows:
        displayId=0, name='5cf6bc4 org.mm.myajpp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity'
2022-08-15 13:07:27.173 1477-3646/? I/OplusAppSwitchManagerService:  handleAppVisible , r = ActivityRecord{2620236 u0 org.mm.myajpp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity t2478}
2022-08-15 13:07:27.181 12493-12523/org.mm.myajpp I/python: Android kivy bootstrap done. __name__ is __main__
2022-08-15 13:07:27.289 12493-12523/org.mm.myajpp I/python: [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /data/user/0/org.mm.myajpp/files/app/.kivy/logs/kivy_22-08-15_3.txt
2022-08-15 13:07:27.289 12493-12523/org.mm.myajpp I/python: [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0
2022-08-15 13:07:27.289 12493-12523/org.mm.myajpp I/python: [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/data/user/0/org.mm.myajpp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/__init__.pyc"
2022-08-15 13:07:27.291 12493-12523/org.mm.myajpp I/python: [INFO   ] [KivyMD      ] 1.1.0.dev0, git-Unknown, 2022-08-15 (installed at "/data/user/0/org.mm.myajpp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivymd/__init__.pyc")
2022-08-15 13:07:27.304 12493-12523/org.mm.myajpp I/python:    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myajpp/arm64-v8a/kivymd/__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
2022-08-15 13:07:27.304 12493-12523/org.mm.myajpp I/python:    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myajpp/arm64-v8a/kivymd/font_definitions.py", line 10, in <module>
2022-08-15 13:07:27.305 12493-12523/org.mm.myajpp I/python:    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myajpp/arm64-v8a/kivy/core/text/__init__.py", line 85, in <module>
2022-08-15 13:07:27.305 12493-12523/org.mm.myajpp I/python:    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myajpp/arm64-v8a/kivy/graphics/__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
2022-08-15 13:07:27.305 12493-12523/org.mm.myajpp I/python:  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy.graphics.instructions'
2022-08-15 13:07:27.355 1477-3646/? I/WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{5cf6bc4 u0 org.mm.myajpp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity}
2022-08-15 13:07:27.355 1477-3646/? W/InputManager-JNI: Input channel object '5cf6bc4 org.mm.myajpp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity (client)' was disposed without first being removed with the input manager!
2022-08-15 13:07:27.363 1477-3299/? D/TheiaManager: ActivityRecord{2620236 u0 org.mm.myajpp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity t2478} callDeclaredMethod : com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.getPid param[] null args[]null
2022-08-15 13:07:27.368 1477-3299/? W/ActivityTaskManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{2620236 u0 org.mm.myajpp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity t2478}: app died, no saved state
2022-08-15 13:07:27.374 1477-3299/? D/TaskExtImpl: remove ActivityRecord{2620236 u0 org.mm.myajpp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity t-1 f}} to mActivityRecordSum = Counter{ }
2022-08-15 13:07:27.378 1283-1283/? D/OplusLayer: ~Layer() sequence=62510, name=5cf6bc4 org.mm.myajpp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity#0 0xb4000071b909cb80
2022-08-15 13:07:27.382 1283-1283/? D/OplusLayer: ~Layer() sequence=62511, name=org.mm.myajpp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity#0 0xb4000071b90f4640
2022-08-15 13:07:27.382 1283-1283/? D/OplusLayer: ~Layer() sequence=62514, name=Bounds for - org.mm.myajpp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity#0 0xb4000071b90b74c0
2022-08-15 13:07:27.382 1283-1283/? D/OplusLayer: ~Layer() sequence=62515, name=SurfaceView[org.mm.myajpp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity]#0 0xb4000071b90bc940
2022-08-15 13:07:27.382 1283-1283/? D/OplusLayer: ~Layer() sequence=62517, name=Background for SurfaceView[org.mm.myajpp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity]#0 0xb4000071b90ce680
2022-08-15 13:07:27.382 1283-1283/? D/OplusLayer: ~Layer() sequence=62516, name=SurfaceView[org.mm.myajpp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity](BLAST)#0 0xb4000071b90c1f80
2022-08-15 13:07:27.394 1283-1283/? D/OplusLayer: ~Layer() sequence=62502, name=ActivityRecord{2620236 u0 org.mm.myajpp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity#0 0xb4000071b9026880```

Where lies the error? Any help appreciated!
````

Answer (score 0):

Just add `kivy_garden` in requirements in your buildozer.spec file.

Comment: I didn't even use kivy garden? So I have add it anyway?

Comment: I also faced this issue but solved after adding kivy_garden in requirements. Just try this

Answer (score 0):

Just Add Kivymd in requirements in your buildozer.spec

requirements = python3,kivy==master,https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip